# pdo + sql insert select group by NOT WORKING

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

can someone help me with this pdo:

- idea:

> insert into 'table 1',  rows obtained with a select from table 0

- structure of table1:

  id_i (int Primary AI)| id_e (int)| date (datetime)| num (text) | sum (decimal 14,2)| stat (tinyint)

bonus question: any idea for optimazing the sql request if 1000+ rows?

my code:

```
$query = " INSERT INTO table1 (id_e, date, string, sum, stat)
    SELECT id_s, NOW(), GROUP_CONCAT(id_r), SUM(bud), 0
    FROM table0 as e
    WHERE e.stat=4 AND e.datetime<='$date' GROUP BY e.id_s
    ";

    try 
    {
    $bdd = new PDO('xxxx');
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    die('Erreur: '.$e->getMessage());   
    }
    $request= $bdd->prepare($query);

    if ($bdd->execute()) {
        echo 'ok';
    }
    else {
        echo 'no';
    }
```

As you understand I got 'no'! But if I do only the **SELECT** it's working!

Comment: If your not getting an error then turn on error reporting for debugging (`$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after making connection)

Comment: Thank you Nigel, your clue was a great help!! Now the problem is fixed (problem with colum names)!

Comment: Just added as answer so it's easier for future readers  to find solutions.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Don't do this

Comment: @Strawberry why?

Comment: Because it contravenes the first principle of normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry I think you are speaking about GROUP_CONCAT , but in this case I didn't find better option

Comment: A better option is to not store derived data. Also, any time you have enumerated table or column names, it's a sure sign that something has gone very wrong with your design.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry master Yoda, but I didn't really got the point on the last answer. If you have some good articles about this, maybe should it be good to provide for other readers?

Comment: Any good article on database normalisation you need, hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not getting an error then turn on error reporting for debugging

```
$bdd = new PDO('xxxx');
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
```

This will allow you to see what errors are coming out, but it's not good for end users to see these sorts of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the error you are getting?

In 5.7 the sqlmode is set by default to

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.
```

Remove the clause ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. You can remove like this:

```
 SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Please try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: Why would you remove that setting? In this case the values not present in the group by part of the query are constants (now() and 0). But turning ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY off will open the way for queries where the 0 is actually a column. That will result in unexpected results: say there are both 0 and 1 possible. You will end up with only one of those 2.  It allows crippled query's to run without warning

Answer (score -1):

add the missing columns to the group-by:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id_e, date, string, sum, stat)
    SELECT id_s, NOW() as tm, GROUP_CONCAT(id_r), SUM(bud), 0 AS stat
    FROM table0 as e
    WHERE e.stat=4 AND e.datetime<='$date' 
    GROUP BY e.id_s, tm, stat
```